# Flutter run multiple unit tests in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter, testing

I have been following this Flutter doc:
https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/testing/unit/introduction

And I can run the test in Android Studio if I open the file and run it by tapping the run button.

Thing is I want to run all tests with the push of one button, like in Xcode.

How to do that in Android Studio?

What I did:

Created two dumb tests, just for the sake of having them.

[image]

Created test configuration with `All in Directory` option and pointed to test directory:

[image]

And after hitting Play button I get:

```
Failed to load "/Users/martinberger/Dev/flutter_apps/iCash/icash/test/second_test.dart":
Test never connected to test harness.
Test: /Users/martinberger/Dev/flutter_apps/iCash/icash/test/second_test.dart
Shell: /Users/martinberger/Dev/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/darwin-x64/flutter_tester
```

So the first test complete, but next one, do not even start.

Of the dozen or so tutorials/blogs/docs I have read about this, they all focus on writing one test and running it by right-clicking or by having it open and clicking Play button.

I am coming from iOS/Xcode background so is there something I should know about running a simple test suite in Android Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can type `flutter test` and then the directory you want in the terminal.

So in your case: `flutter test test/`